# Add apiserver extraArgs/extraVolumes in a live cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kube-apiserver

I have a Kubernetes cluster 1.17, and I want to add some `extraArgs` and `extraVolumes` (like in https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/) in the apiserver. Usually, I update the manifest file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` to apply my new config, then I update the `kubeadm-config` ConfigMap to keep this new configuration for the next Kubernetes upgrade (because static pod manifests are re-generated from this ConfigMap when upgrading).

Is it possible to update only the `kubeadm-config` ConfigMap then apply the configuration with a command like `kubeadm init phase control-plane apiserver` ? What are the risks ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve? What args/volumes you want to add/change ?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. For example, I need to add the extraArg `--authentication-token-webhook-config-file=/etc/kubernetes/conf/ldap.conf` and an extraVolume to mount the the authentication configuration file in the apiserver pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way to go to upgrade `static pod definitions` of `control plane components`, but instead of [init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/) command I guess you meant [upgrade](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/).

`$ kubeadm upgrade` command consults each time current cluster configuration from [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) (`$ kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml`) before applying changes.

Talking about risks, you can try to envision them by studying output of kubeadm upgrade diff command, e.g.

`kubeadm upgrade diff v1.20.4`. More details in [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/#cmd-upgrade-diff). You could also try to use `--dry-run` flag from [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/#cmd-upgrade-node). It won't change any state, it will display the actions that would be performed.

As addition, you could also read about `--experimental-patches` from [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options)

Comment: The `kubectl upgrade` command worried me because I didn't know if we could update only the configuration, without the version. But I just tested and it's OK. As usual, `kubectl upgrade apply` on the first node, then `kubectl upgrade node` on other control-plane nodes worked. Thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: Cannot edit my comment: I would write `kubeadm` in the place of `kubectl` obviously.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean change the apiserver config in a live cluster,you can change /etc/kubernetes/manifest/kubeadm-apiserver.conf to apply.

But you must be careful becouse the old static pod will be killed before the new pod ready.